# How do you properly prepare a %LIKE% SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, wpdb, sql

I'd like to use a LIKE %text% statement while still using the WordPress $wpdb class to sanitize and prepare input.

```
SELECT column_1 from `prefix_my_table` WHERE column_2 LIKE '%something%';
```

I've tried something like this to no avail:

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT column_1 from `{$wpdb->base_prefix}my_table` WHERE column_2 LIKE %s;", like_escape($number_to_put_in_like));
```

How do you properly prepare a %LIKE% SQL statement using the WordPress database class?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The `$wpdb->esc_like` function exists in WordPress because the regular database escaping does not escape `%` and `_` characters. This means you can add them in your arguments to `wpdb::prepare()` without problem. This is also [what I see in the core WordPress code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-admin/includes/user.php#L689):

```
$wpdb->prepare(" AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities' AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value LIKE %s", '%' . $this->role . '%');
```

So your code would look like:

```
$wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT
        column_1
    FROM
        `{$wpdb->base_prefix}my_table`
    WHERE
        column_2 LIKE %s;",
    '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($number_to_put_in_like) . '%'
);
```

You can also add `%%` in your query to get a literal `%` (`wpdb::prepare()` uses `vsprintf()` in the background, [which has this syntax](http://php.net/sprintf)), but remember that **your string will not be quoted**, you must add the quotes yourself (which is not what you usually have to do in `wpdb::prepare()`.

Comment: what are the `{}` for ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales: To indicate that everything inside it should be considered [a variable expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php), otherwise it would only see `$wpdb`, and ignore the `->prefix` after it.

Comment: @JanFabry Close. I would correct the comment to say: "... otherwise it would see all of `$wpdb->base_prefixmy_table` and try to to look up `base_prefixmy_table` property instead of just `base_prefix`.

Comment: Also a thing to mention is that the % are being replaced by a stupidly long hash. Which does look wrong when you var_dump the sql output. After hours of searching its noted here that this is a Wordpress 4.8.3 security fix for sql injection. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914094/7977916

Answer (score 10):

You need to double percent so they are no treated like fragment markers by `wpdb->prepare()`:

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT column_1 from `{$wpdb->base_prefix}my_table` WHERE column_2 LIKE %%%s%%;", $wpdb->esc_like( $number_to_put_in_like));
```

PS not sure this is best/only way to do it.

Comment: Remember that **you must add the quotes around the string yourself**, because [`wpdb::prepare` will only add them for a `%s` that is not preceded by an `%`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L899). The final part of your query should be `WHERE column_2 LIKE '%%%s%%'`.

Comment: This worked great along with @JanFabry 's tip

Comment: Liked this answer best due to use of esc_like and @JanFabry 's comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it that I've checked and it works:

```
$search_text = "%" . $_GET['some_text'] . "%";

$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mix_library WHERE ml_setting_name LIKE %s", 
        $search_text 
    ) 
);
```

Replace variables to suit your needs.

Comment: You should escape `%` characters (by using `like_escape()`. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Answer (score 1):

```
$safe_sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wp_track_table $sql",["*yoursecretkey*".$_POST['search']."*yoursecretkey*"]);

$safe_sql = str_replace("*yoursecretkey*", "%", $safe_sql);
```

I found a suitable solution with the above codes. Definitely try it.

Comment: So your approach is to pass a random string into prepare() and replace that with percents afterwards? That feels like you're fighting WordPress.

Comment: Basically templating, I suppose. Not the cleanest, but certainly one approach! Thank you.