# How to Use Wildcards in $wpdb Queries Using $wpdb->get_results & $wpdb->prepare?

Tags: query, wpdb, sql, variables, escaping

I am attempting to make a custom search for BuddyPress groups.

**Here is my method:**

```
public function search_groups($string){
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
        "
        SELECT * 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}bp_groups 
        WHERE `name` LIKE '%%s%'
        AND `description` LIKE '%%s%' 
        AND `status` = 'public'
        ORDER BY `name` ASC
        ",
        $string,
        $string
    ));
    if(!empty($results)){
        $return = $results;
    } else{
        $return = false;    
    }
    return $return;
}
```

However, I am receiving a WordPress database error. I'm pretty sure it's due to the fact that I'm using `$wpdb->prepare();`, since it uses % signs for replacing variables.

**Let's take a look at this portion of my query:**

```
WHERE `name` LIKE '%%s%'
AND `description` LIKE '%%s%'
```

That just looks like trouble. Is there any way that I can accomplish something along the lines of...

```
WHERE `name` LIKE '%{$string}%'
AND `description` LIKE '%{$string}%'
```

and still use the `$wpdb->prepare();` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you properly prepare a %LIKE% SQL statement?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/how-do-you-properly-prepare-a-like-sql-statement)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out a solution to my question.

First of all, in my original query, I should have specified OR instead of AND for searching between group names and group descriptions. (It was skewing the results.)

And I needed to double escape my '%'s in the LIKE statements.

**Here is the updated query which works correctly:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}bp_groups 
WHERE `name` LIKE '%%%s%%'
OR `description` LIKE '%%%s%%' 
AND `status` = 'public'
ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

**Example using `$wpdb->query` and `$wpdb->prepare`:**

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
    'DELETE FROM %s WHERE `option_name` LIKE %s',
    $wpdb->options,
    $wpdb->esc_like(PLUGIN_SLUG . '%%')
) );
```

Comment: You should use $wpdb->esc_like() in your code. Otherwise the PLUGIN_SLUG can mess it up, if there’s ‘%’ in it. (Probably it won’t, since it’s a slug, but...)