# Syntax for $wpdb->prepare when searching in two columns

Tags: wpdb, sql

I have this working statement for searching a single column in my database:

```
$foods = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT id, foodname, namevariations, calories, carbs, fat, protein, sodium FROM foodsTable WHERE namevariations like %s", "%$search_text%"), ARRAY_A );
```

I would like to include another column in the search called "foodname" but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

How should I formulate my prepare statement so that I'm searching "namevariations" OR "foodname" and a match in either column will select that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part after `WHERE` decides which columns are searched.

So you need to change it this way:

```
$foods = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT id, foodname, namevariations, calories, carbs, fat, protein, sodium FROM foodsTable WHERE namevariations like %1$s OR foodname like %1$s",
        '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search_text ) . '%'
    ),
    ARRAY_A
);
```

Also you were using LIKE queries incorrectly. If the `$search_text` contained `%` character, it would be interpreted as wildcard and not as simple character. That's why I've added some escaping in your code. More on this topic here: [How do you properly prepare a %LIKE% SQL statement?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/how-do-you-properly-prepare-a-like-sql-statement)

Comment: Hi! For some reason I'm getting this error with your suggestion: WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%1 OR recipename like %1' at line 1]
SELECT * FROM recipestable WHERE recipetags like %1 OR recipename like %1;
[]

Comment: Got it to work with this:$like = '%'. $wpdb->esc_like($searchExpression) . '%'; 
$sql_content = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ( post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' or post_content LIKE '%%%s%%' )", $like, $like ); $post_id = $wpdb->get_var($sql_content);

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work like this:

```
$recipes = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM recipestable WHERE ( recipetags LIKE '%%%s%%' or recipename LIKE '%%%s%%' )", $like, $like ), ARRAY_A )
```

Comment: Your answer is off to a good start. Please consider explaining how and why this code solves the problem so others can learn from it. Check the [guide to answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for further advice.

Answer (score 0):

For people landing from Google search, you can use numbered placeholders (%1$s, %2$s, etc.) in [$wpdb->prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to use the same search term on multiple columns.

The WP documentation states that: "*for compatibility with old behavior, numbered or formatted string placeholders (eg, %1$s, %5s) will not have quotes added by this function, so should be passed with appropriate quotes around them.*"
Since we use numbered placeholders we will also have to put the quotes:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE \'%1$s\' OR other_column_name LIKE \'%1$s\'', $search_term );
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```

Literal percentage signs need to be written like %%:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE \'%%%1$s%%\' OR other_column_name LIKE \'%%%1$s%%\'', $search_term );
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```

So the code from the initial question would look like:

```
$foods = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT id, foodname, namevariations, calories, carbs, fat, protein, sodium FROM foodsTable WHERE namevariations LIKE \'%%%1$s%%\' OR foodname LIKE \'%%%1$s%%\'', $search_text ), ARRAY_A );
```